# Require Error in test for a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a project tree as below:

```
├── bin
├── fpgrowth-ruby-0.0.1.gem
├── fpgrowth-ruby.gemspec
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── fpgrowth
│   │   ├── fptree
│   │   │   ├── builder
│   │   │   │   ├── first_pass.rb
│   │   │   │   └── second_pass.rb
│   │   │   ├── fp_tree.rb
│   │   │   └── node.rb
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   └── transaction.rb
│   │   └── ruby
│   │       └── version.rb
│   └── fpgrowth.rb
├── LICENSE.txt
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
└── test
    └── tc_first_pass.rb
```

In the TestCase for first_pass I wrote:

```
require 'test/unit'
require "../lib/fpgrowth/fptree/builder/first_pass"
```

Then I get this:

```
ruby test/tc_first_pass.rb 
/home/damien/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ../lib/fpgrowth/fptree/builder/first_pass (LoadError)
    from /home/damien/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from test/tc_first_pass.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Something is wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: Do you need to include the file extension, as in `require "../lib/fpgrowth/fptree/builder/first_pass.rb"` ?

Comment: @sawa Please don't be condescending in your commit message. Not everybody on earth learned English in a Connecticut's elementary school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -I flag on the ruby command line, to specify a require path at runtime.

from your top level directory

```
ruby -I lib test/tc_first_pass.rb
```

The above tells the ruby interpreter to include /lib in the load path for this execution only.

Then for your require line,

```
require 'fpgrowth/fptree/builder/first_pass'
```

For gem building, and organizing your source I suggest reading chapters on organizing your source, and distributing and packaging your code from the Programming Ruby book found here: http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9

Answer (score 1):

You can't require files like that unless you use `require_relative`.

Barring that, you should do is alter `$LOAD_PATH` to include `../lib`.

Comment: I must certainly use the $LOAD_PATH trick for testing my gem. Or is it better to build la gem and require it then in my tests ?

Comment: You might want to adjust your `$LOAD_PATH` for testing and let Rubygems handle the adjustment when your gem's installed. This makes your test environment similar to what it's like when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [File](http://apidock.com/ruby/File) class-methods to help you.

First is to start off at the directory not relative to the `cwd`, but relative to the file calling the require. They might not be the same.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "../lib/fpgrowth/fptree/builder/first_pass"
```

This, however, is not very portable and can be cleaned up by using the `join` class-method:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib', 'fpgrowth', 'fptree', 'builder', 'first_pass')
```

But you probably find yourself adding this all over the place, not? In that case, consider adding a helper in `fpgrowth.rb`:

```
def self.root
  Pathname.new(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
end
```

Now, you can use that helper all over the place:

```
FpGrowth.root #=> "/absolute/path/to/fpgrowth/lib"
FpGrowth.root.join("fpgrowth", "fbtree", "builder") #=> "/absolute/path/to/fpgrowth/lib/fpbrowth/fbtree/builder"
```